# ConfigParser does not load sections when run via crontab

Tags: python-2.7, configparser

When I run python script via command line, everything works just perfect, but wehn the script is being running from cron ConfigParser creates an empty list of sections

```
me = singleton.SingleInstance()

######### Accessing the configuration file #######################################
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('./matrix.cfg')
sections = config.sections()

######### Build the current map ##################################################
print sections
```

Here is the cron job

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /etc/portmatrix/matrix.py | logger
```

and here is the output

```
Feb 12 12:59:01 dns01 CRON[30879]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/python /etc/portmatrix/matrix.py | logger)
Feb 12 12:59:01 dns01 logger: []
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ConfigParser tries to read the file `./matrix.cfg`.

Now the path of this file is `./` which means *in the current directory*.

So what assumption do you make about the *current directory* when being run from `cron`? (I guess you have a file `/etc/portmatrix/matrix.cfg` and you assume that `./` really means "*in the same directory as the running script*" - this however is not true)

The simple fix is to provide the *full* path to the configuration file. E.g.:

```
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('/etc/portmatrix/matrix.cfg')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Ive used 4 hours trying to figure it out why my cron wasnt running..

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar situation and I was able to fix it thanks to umläute's answer.

I'm using os however, so in your case, this would be something like:

```
import os
...
base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.join(base_path, 'matrix.cfg')
```